# How to re.sub() a optional matching group using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

My problem is quite simple.

I have a URL, sometimes it ends with specific characters. If they are present, I would like to add them to my new URL.

```
test1 = "url#123"
test2 = "url"

r = re.sub(r"url(#[0-9]+)?", r"new_url\1", test1)
# Expected result: "new_url#123"
# Actual result: "new_url#123"

r = re.sub(r"url(#[0-9]+)?", r"new_url\1", test2)
# Expected result: "new_url"
# Actual result: "error: unmatched group"
```

Of course, I can not just do `re.sub("url", "new_url", test)`, because for example it could be "url/123" and in this case I do not wish to make amendments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use optional matching group in replacement string.

How about following approach?

```
>>> import re
>>> test1 = "url#123"
>>> test2 = "url"
>>> re.sub(r"url((?:#[0-9]+)?)", r"new_url\1", test1)
new_url#123
>>> re.sub(r"url((?:#[0-9]+)?)", r"new_url\1", test2)
new_url
```

BTW, if you use [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you can use optional matching group:

```
>>> import regex
>>> test1 = "url#123"
>>> test2 = "url"
>>> regex.sub(r"url(#[0-9]+)?", r"new_url\1", test1)
'new_url#123'
>>> regex.sub(r"url(#[0-9]+)?", r"new_url\1", test2)
'new_url'
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you recommend me to use the regex module all the time, or just in this case? What are the main differences between re and regex?

Comment: @user3779937, No, I'm not recommend to use it all the time. `regex` is not a standard library module; you need to install separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [4]: re.sub(r"url(#[0-9]+|$)", r"new_url\1", test1)
Out[4]: 'new_url#123'

In [5]: re.sub(r"url(#[0-9]+|$)", r"new_url\1", test2)
Out[5]: 'new_url'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r'url(#*.*)', r'url\1', test1)
```